# Polling SVN After Build Completes

Tags: svn, jenkins, polling

I currently have a Jenkins build that triggers a build whenever there is a change in SVN. I currently have it set to poll svn for changes every 5mins. So once a change is detected it will start the build. However, once the build starts and another change is detected in the next 5 mins it will attempt to build again and go into the waiting queue. Well you can imagine if 3 or more changes are made withing a 15mins period I now have 3 more jobs in the queue backing things up. Is there a way to tell it not to poll again until the current build is completed or is there a way to have only one job in the queue and kill the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Jenkins to wait 'x' seconds after the check in change before starting the build. I have the same issue, dev's doing multiple check ins.

There are two options to configure this, a system wide option or a per-job option.

The system wide option is under Manage -> Configure System -> Quiet Period. It is in seconds.

The per job option is under Advanced Project Options, and is also called Quiet Period.

If you set quiet period to 90, Jenkins will wait until 90 seconds after the last detected check in before starting the build.